# Matching a character before or after a word, but not both in regex

Tags: regex

Lets say I need to match a word `word` where there may be a period before word or after word but not both. Then `word`, `.word`, and `word.` should be matched, but `.word.` should not be matched. How would I match this and capture what occurred before and after the word?

That was a simplified example that I'll need to extend to more complicated cases. For example, now the symbols `.` and `'` may occur before or after the word, but they can only occur once. So for example, `.word`, `'word`, `word.'`, and `.word'` are just a few of the valid matches, but something like `.'word.'` shouldn't match, or even `.'word'`.

The above example is my main priority, but an added bonus would be the order in which the period and apostrophe are added. Thus `'.word` and `.'word` should both match. I think one way that should work for this is `\.?'?|'?\.?word`, but I was hoping for some way where the number of statements in the OR clause doesn't depend on the number of symbols.

Comment: When you say a literal period before or after, do you mean a literal period or a regexp period (wildcard for [almost] any character)?

Comment: Would these matches appear in the middle of a larger string such as `something here .word other stuff`, or is it safe to assume that `.word` is the entire string?

Comment: Are both `word.` and `.'word'.` bad matches, while `word` and `.'word'` are good?

Comment: @Wiseguy There will be multiple words in the same format. So one possible string is `.word word. .word`. Thus all words are of this format. The words will be different words, but I can figure that out myself. For now you can assume the string will be like this one.

@LarryBattle word. is a good match. .'word'. is a bad match. word is a good match. .'word' is a bad match. Another way of putting it is both symbols (the period and apostrophe) can occur a total of 0 or 1 times, but that 1 time can be before or after the word.

Comment: the word "word" is starting to look really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It needed a bit time more in order to handle properly the case in which `word` occurrences are at the begin or at the end of the string.

```
 "(?:\.word(?:[^.]|$))|(?:(?:[^.]|^)word(?:[^.]|$))|(?:(?:[^.]|^)word\.)"
```

The same `regexp` with **Lookaheads** and **Lookbehinds** (tested in python):

```
 "(?:\.word(?:(?!\.)|$))|(?:(?:(?<!\.)|^)word(?:(?!\.)|$))|(?:(?:(?<!\.)|^)word\.)"
```

It works:

```
 re.findall(pattern(above), '.word. .word .word. word.'") // return ['.word ', ' word.']
```

Comment: What if `word` is at the beginning or end of the string? This assumes there are characters on both sides. Also, need to escape `\.` if used literally. _Also_, I think the asker wants to apply this to a general case, not just specifically `.` characters.

Comment: @Wiseguy Yes, I am looking for a general case. And you are right about the issues with this answer.

Comment: I'm trying so hard not to shamelessly steal reputation by just reanswering this with escaped periods.  Especially since I suggested an edit.  **Especially** since it's been edited since I suggested it, and the .s still arent escaped.

Comment: Could this be generalized by using negative lookaheads with backreferences?

Comment: Honestly I'm not an expert in lookaheads and in lookbehinds :)

Comment: @gsingh2011: I've changed the regular expression so that now it uses Lookahead and Lookbehind ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works in javascript with the good and bad values you supplied.

```
var func = function (str) {
    var result = true, match, re = /^([^a-z]+)[a-z]+([^a-z]+)$/i;
    if (re.test(str)) {
        match = re.exec(str);
        re = new RegExp("[" + match[1] + "]");
        result = !re.test(match[2]);
    }
    return result;
};
```

Here's a simple explanation. 
If the string contains a non-letter before and after a letter, then the non-letters get extracted and tested against each other. Negate the result of the test to figure out if the word is good or bad.

```
str = .'word.
".'", "word", "."
/[.']/.test( "." )
```

The `func` function expects a word( characters with no spaces) as a string.
If you want to check a sentence then split by spaces then check each word.
Something like this.

```
    var sentence = "What does .'words'. means?";
var words = sentence.split(/\s+/g);
    var areWordsOk;
for( var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++ ){
    areWordsOk = func( words[i] );
    if( !areWordsOk ){
        throw new Error( "bad word." ); // error is thrown
    }
}
```

Here's are my test cases. 
Live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tb68G/2
Here's the source for the test cases.

```
var func = function (str) {
    var result = true, match, re = /^([^a-z]+)[a-z]+([^a-z]+)$/i;
    if (re.test(str)) {
        match = re.exec(str);
        re = new RegExp("[" + match[1] + "]");
        result = !re.test(match[2]);
    }
    return result;
};
test("test good values", function () {
    var arr = [
        "word",
        ".word",
        "word.",
        ".word",
        "'word",
        "word.'",
        ".word'"
    ];
    var i = arr.length,
    str;
    while (i--) {
        str = arr[i];
        equal(func(str), true, str + " should be true.");
    }
});
test("test bad values", function () {
    var arr = [
        ".word.",
        ".'word.'",
        ".'word'.",
        ".'word'"
    ];
    var i = arr.length,
    str;
    while (i--) {
        str = arr[i];
        equal(func(str), false, str + " should be false.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Not quite.  `^([^a-z])+` consumes all non-letter characters preceding the word, but it only *captures* the last one.  Then `(\1)$` looks for that same character at the end of the string.  Result: it correctly identifies `.'word'` as bad, but not `'word'.`.  More importantly, you're assuming the regex is being applied to standalone strings, but I think the idea is to find matches within a longer string.

Answer (score -1):

i was thinking regex is a cool thing...
but sometime, you need to use other methods,
looking at such a monstrous expression for simple thing....

i say CODE IT!

```
    int findWord(string text, string word, char ch, int startIdx = 0)
    {
        while(startIdx < text.Length)
        {
            int indexOf = text.IndexOf(word, startIdx);
            if (indexOf < 0) return -1;

            char preChar = (char) 0;
            char postChar = (char) 0;

            if (indexOf > 0)
                preChar = text[indexOf - 1];

            if (indexOf < text.Length - word.Length)
                postChar = text[indexOf + word.Length];


            if ((preChar == ch) ^ (postChar == ch))
            {
                return indexOf;
            }
            startIdx = indexOf + word.Length + 1;
        } 
    }
```

Not so simple,  and it is more then one line :)
but performs better, and can be understood if you read it after a month or two.

Answer (score -1):

Which flavor?  If it's JavaScript, this should work:

```
(?:^|[^\w.'])(?=[.']*(word))(?!'*\.'*\1'*\.)(?!\.*'\.*\1\.*')([.']*)\1([.']*)
```

Explanation:

- `(?:^|[^\w.'])` - Makes sure `word` isn't the tail end of a larger word, and prevents the regex from bypassing the leading delimiters (`.` or `'`) if they're there.
- `(?=[.']*(word\b))` - Makes sure `word` is not the *beginning* of a longer word and that it's preceded by nothing but your chosen delimiters.  The word is not consumed at this time, it's just captured in group #1, so it can be used to anchor the next two lookaheads.
- `(?!'*\.'*\1'*\.)` - Still positioned before the leading delimiters (if any), this makes sure that, if there's a `.` before the word, there isn't one after it.
- `(?!\.*'\.*\1\.*')` - This does the same for `'`.
- `([.']*)\1([.']*)` - Finally, goes ahead and consumes the word, along with any leading or trailing delimiters, capturing those in groups #2 and #3.

If you're using a flavor that supports lookbehind, it probably won't help.  Most flavors place severe restrictions on what can be matched in a lookbehind, rendering it useless for this task.  The JavaScript regex above is probably still your best option.  However, this regex works in .NET and JGSoft, the only flavors I know of to support completely unrestricted lookbehinds:

```
(?<=(?:\.(?<dot1>)|'(?<apos1>))*)\bword\b(?=(?:\.(?<dot2>)|'(?<apos2>))*)(?!\k<dot1>\k<dot2>|\k<apos1>\k<apos2>)
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=(?:\.(?<dot1>)|'(?<apos1>))*)` - Scans backward for delimiter characters.  As each one is matched, the empty capturing group following it effectively marks that character as having been seen.
- `\bword\b` - Consumes the word.
- `(?=(?:\.(?<dot2>)|'(?<apos2>))*)` - Scans ahead for more delimiters and checks them off just like the lookbehind did.
- `(?!\k<dot1>\k<dot2>|\k<apos1>\k<apos2>)` - Asserts that neither the dot nor the apostrophe appears both before and after the word.  A backreference to an empty group never consumes any characters, it merely asserts that the group has participated in the match.

After those two flavors, Java's lookbehind is probably the most flexible, but it's also notoriously buggy.  I *should* be able to port this regex to Java by changing the first `*` to `{0,2}`, but it just throws that "no obvious maximum length" exception.  Again, you're probably better off using the JavaScript-compatible regex above.

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for. First, I'm testing in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but I'm using Java, so if it works in Java that's all that matters. Secondly, the issue with this is that things like ..word should not be matched, but they are. Imagine that . and ' are modifiers that can only be applied to the word once. They can be applied before or after, but in both spots doesn't make sense. Also putting two of the same modifier before the word doesn't make sense either. Finally, words like %word or 6word match, but they do. If you could update your answer that would be great.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that two of the same delimiter might appear on the same side. That makes the problem much more... interesting. ;)  In fact, I think you should give up trying to do it all with one regex.  Simply try upgrading either of these regexes to handle three delimiters instead of just two, and you end up with an unmaintainable monster.  That's usually a good sign that regex is maybe not the best tool for the job.