# How do I match a character before or after a capturing group in regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-re, capture-group

I have a Python script with a regex pattern that searches for the word `employee_id` if there is an equals sign immediately before or after.

```
import re

pattern = r"(=employee_id|employee_id=)"

print(re.search(pattern, "=employee_id").group(1))  # =employee_id
print(re.search(pattern, "employee_id=").group(1))  # employee_id=
print(re.search(pattern, "=employee_id=").group(1))  # =employee_id
print(re.search(pattern, "employee_id"))  # None
print(re.search(pattern, "employee_identity="))  # None
```

**How can I modify my regex pattern to only capture the `employee_id` part of the string without the equals sign?**

```
# Desired results
print(re.search(pattern, "=employee_id").group(1))  # employee_id
print(re.search(pattern, "employee_id=").group(1))  # employee_id
print(re.search(pattern, "=employee_id=").group(1))  # employee_id
print(re.search(pattern, "employee_id"))  # None
print(re.search(pattern, "employee_identity="))  # None
```

---

I attempted to use capture groups, but putting parentheses around `employee_id` meant my results were split between two capture groups:

```
pattern = r"=(employee_id)|(employee_id)="
print(re.search(pattern, "employee_id=").group(1))  # None
print(re.search(pattern, "employee_id=").group(2))  # employee_id
```

Using optional groups would match an `employee_id` without any equals sign.

```
(?:=)?(employee_id)(?:=)?
```

I also do not want to [exclude matches where the character is both before and after the word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11140770/3357935).

Comment: `=(employee_id)(?!=)|(?<!=)(employee_id)=` -- Is this what you want? Or do you explicitly want to have `employee_id` in a single group?

Comment: I explicitly want `employee_id` in a single group so I can avoid having to check which group contains the match.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(?<==)employee_id|employee_id(?==)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/UaLnJ9/1)

Or if you want it matched inside a capture group

```
((?<==)employee_id|employee_id(?==))
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/johbtB/1)

This matches `employee_id` if there is `=` before or after the string

---

EDIT: Python example:

```py
import re

pattern = r"(?<==)employee_id|employee_id(?==)"

print(re.search(pattern, "=employee_id").group(0))  # =employee_id
print(re.search(pattern, "employee_id=").group(0))  # employee_id=
print(re.search(pattern, "=employee_id=").group(0))  # =employee_id
```

Prints:

```
employee_id
employee_id
employee_id
```

---

OR: You can add capturing group around the pattern:

You can put capturing group around the pattern:

```py
import re

pattern = r"((?<==)employee_id|employee_id(?==))"

print(re.search(pattern, "=employee_id").group(1))  # =employee_id
print(re.search(pattern, "employee_id=").group(1))  # employee_id=
print(re.search(pattern, "=employee_id=").group(1))  # =employee_id
```

Prints:

```
employee_id
employee_id
employee_id
```

Comment: This has *no* capture groups, and is otherwise essentially equivalent to what the OP explicitly says they do not want.

Comment: @chepner If I've understood right, the OP said `To specify, I do not want two separate capture groups`

Comment: Yes, they want *a* capture group, but some way of specifying that it is not entirely devoid of surrounding `=`s. `=employe_id`, `employee_id=`, and `=employee-id=` are all matches, but `[^=]employee_id[^=]` is not.

Comment: @Stevoisiak I've edited my answer (put some Python examples too.)

Comment: @AndrejKesely My intent was to avoid two separate capture groups where one was empty. In this case I could take the full match as-is, or enclose the entire pattern in a single capture group since the lookarounds are non-capturing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have only one capture group while making sure `=` is either before or after the capture group then use:

```bash
(?:(?<==)|(?=\w+=))(employee_id)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hIMyx5/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Non capture group start

  - `(?<==)`: Assert that we have `=` just before the current position
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?=\w+=)`: Assert that we have 1+ word characters and `=` just after the current position
- `)`: Non capture group end
- `(employee_id)`: Match and capture `employee_id`
- `\b`: Word boundary

Comment: This would also match `employee_identifier=` though, if you use `re.match` or `re.search`

Comment: @decorator-factory: That what OP wants when he wrote: `that searches for the word employee_id if there is an equals sign before or after`

Comment: @anubhava I meant an equals immediately after the word. I have edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @Stevoisiak: We just need a word boundary in my solution. See updated demo in my answer now.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably more complicated than it needs to be, but it is an option.

Python's `re` supports [named groups](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/re.html#index-18), so one would hope that this works:

```
=(?P<employee_id>\d+)(?!=)|(?<!=)(?P<employee_id>\d+)=
```

Unfortunately it doesn't, even though the groups won't ever collide.

```
error: redefinition of group name 'employee_id' as group 2; was group 1 at position 37
```

This does, however, work with the third-party [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) package:

```
>>> import regex
>>> pattern = regex.compile(r"=(?P<employee_id>\d+)(?!=)|(?<!=)(?P<employee_id>\d+)=")
>>> match = pattern.search("And he's like: id=42. So hilarious!")
>>> match
<regex.Match object; span=(17, 20), match='=42'>
>>> match.groupdict()
{'employee_id': '42'}
```

---

If you want to use `re`, you could use a helper function and a slight modification to the pattern:

```py
def unify_groupdict(groupdict):
    result = {}
    for name, match in groupdict.items():
        name = name.rstrip("_")
        if result.get(name) is None:
            result[name] = match
    return result

###

pattern = re.compile(r"=(?P<employee_id>\d+)(?!=)|(?<!=)(?P<employee_id_>\d+)=")
match = pattern.search("And he's like: id=42. So hilarious!")

print(unify_groupdict(match.groupdict()))
# {'employee_id': 42}
```